# What is the difference between .resolve() and .promise()?

Tags: jquery, resolve, deferred, promise

I'm digging into jQuery's deferred features. I've tried several examples on the internet. I understood its concept, but I don't understand the difference between `resolve()` and `promise()`.

What are differences between `resolve()` and `promise()`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Both `resolve()` and `promise()` are methods on the jQuery `Deferred` object.

First a snippet from the jQuery [documentation about Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

> One model for understanding Deferred is to think of it as a
>   chain-aware function wrapper. The deferred.then(), deferred.done(),
>   and deferred.fail() methods specify the functions to be called and the
>   deferred.resolve(args) or deferred.reject(args) methods “call” the
>   functions with the arguments you supply.

With that in mind, `promise()` returns an object that is very similar to the `Deferred` object except that it only has `then()`, `done()`, and `fail()` methods and *does not* have `resolve()` or `reject()`.

From the blog post m-sharp referred to regarding `promise()`:

> This is useful when you want to give to the calling API something to
>   subscribe to, but not the ability to resolve or reject the deferred.